# Python Mock a Function Parameter

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function in `myfile.py` that accepts no arguments. Inside the function I am creating a pandas `DataFrame` based on the data returned from an API call shown as: `df = pd.DataFrame(api_call_from_helper_function().all_the_data())`. I am trying to mock the API call so it doesn't try to actually connect to the API. Below is my attempt:

**myfile.py**

```
def make_dataframe_from_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(api_call_from_helper_function().all_the_data())
    return df
```

**test_myfile.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import myfile
from myfile import make_dataframe_from_data


def test_make_dataframe_from_data(monkeypatch):
    mock_df = MagicMock()
    mock_instance = MagicMock(return_value=mock_df)
    monkeypatch.setattr("pd.DataFrame", mock_instance)
    result = make_dataframe_from_data()
    mock_instance.assert_called_once()
    assert isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame())
```

In this code, the `api_call_from_helper_function()` uses another function I made to make the api call and the appended `.all_the_data()` returns all the data that it got. Right now my tests can mock the api call in `api_call_from_helper_function()` but I can't get it to mock when I pass it as a parameter to `pd.DataFrame`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be `isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame)` ?

Comment: Is there a *reason* `make_dataframe_from_data` takes no arguments? `def make_dataframe_from_data(x): return pd.DataFrame(x.all_the_data())` would be much simpler to test, as you could simply pass an appropriate `Mock` as an argument instead of having to patch anything.

Comment: If it's a callback that expects no argument, then `def make_datafram_from_data(x=None)` makes the argument option, letting it be called with no arguments in production and letting you pass a stub API implementation for testing.

Comment: @AndyHayden That fix doesn't work. I'm getting an error from `monkeypatch` saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pd'`

Comment: @chepner It doesn't take arguments because it doesn't need any arguments. The data is passed through the nested API call. I would also prefer not to clutter the code with unnecessary arguments.